# JMS property breadcrumbId

Tags: apache-camel

How can I put breadcrumb that I have generated into this property? for example I've this class:

```
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

            String uuid = getContext().getUuidGenerator().generateUuid();

            from("someRoute")to("activemq:queue:someQueue");
        }
    }
```

and my question is. How can i put uuid as jms property breadcrumbId?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

        String uuid = getContext().getUuidGenerator().generateUuid();

        from("someRoute").setHeader(Exchange.BREADCRUMB_ID, simple(uuid)).to("activemq:queue:someQueue");
}
```